# Batch Script: Merge Content From .txt List to one file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

On Windows 10 I have this ***.bat***:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%i in (filelist.txt) do (
echo %%~nxi >> output.txt
type "%%~ni*" >> output.txt
echo. >> output.txt
echo. >> output.txt
)
Exit
```

Now what this does is:

- reads *filelist.txt*, which contains names of .txt files like:
  *20180808173105* (without ".txt"
- searches for those files: *20180808173105.txt*
- copies name of files (without ".txt") into *output.txt*
- inserts content of files
- inserts two blank lines
- repeats whole process for all files named in *filelist.txt*
- --> It works fine! (or do you see any exception where this might malfunction?)

This inserts the full contents of a text file according to a list.
Can I modify it, so

1. not the whole content of a .txt, but **only a part of it is inserted?**
   For example, everything from just after "title:" to just before `"<!--"`
2. if the filelist had a **hierarchical structure (outline)**, it could
   be preserved, like so:

> ```
> #201508081213
> ###201609101219
> ```

to

```
#201508081213
TEXT
###201609101219
TEXT
```

I am using this to convert Outlines (using only the file names) to a rough first draft of text for writing articles and blogs

Comment: I am sorry if my question is unclear, I am not a native English speaker nor a programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

2> output.txt echo.

@>&3 (
    echo Debug Information
    echo -----------------
)

for /f "delims=" %%A in (filelist.txt) do (
    for %%B in ("%%~nA*") do call :read "%%~B"
) >> output.txt

exit /b

:read
setlocal
set "line="

echo(%~nx1

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%C in ("%~1") do (
    set "line=%%C"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('call echo "%%line:~0,4%%"') do (
        @>&3 echo File: "%~1"  Test: %%D == "<!--"
        if %%D == "<!--" (
            @>&3 echo Found: "<!--"
            echo.
            echo.
            exit /b 0
        )
    )

    call echo(%%line%%
)

echo.
echo.
exit /b 0
```

### Note

Not the best language for this task. Had to avoid
`enabledelayedexpansion` as to known use of `!` in `<!--`.
Used `call` even though `<` and some other characters
could cause issue.

`for /f` loops do not normally process empty lines so
hope that is not a problem.

Hierarchical structure depends on the order in `filelist.txt`.
The structure of a document can vary and I cannot consider
what the correct order might be. The use of a wildcard gives
some doubt. A filename `#a` will find `#a1` and `#a2` so
placement of 3 headings is unknown.

I have left in the std stream 3 messages for your
understanding of operation with the `<!--` test.
Std stream 1 is the output that goes to file.

### Operation

The file `output.txt` is erased before echoing text to the file.

The 1st `for` loop reads each line of the `filelist.txt` file.
The nested `for` loop gets the filenames with a wildcard.
Each `call` to label `:read` passes the argument of a filename.

In the label of `:read`, the filename is echoed.
A `for` loop reads lines from the filename.
Each line is stored in variable named `line`.
The nested `for` loop will use `call echo` to expand
the variable `line` and echoes the 1st 4 characters.
A comparison is done to test if it is `<!--` and if so,
`echo` 2 newlines and then the label is exited.
If not, `echo` each line. `echo` 2 newlines is done at
the end of the label before exiting.

Comment: Thank you! It works!  I did not know '>' and '!' could cause troubles. It really looks quiet complicated. I doubt I could have gotten this anytime soon with all those 'for' loops. Also thank  you for the explaining you did!